# Does YARN shared cache support Kerberos authentication?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, kerberos

I am trying to use YARN Shared Cache in a Kerberized cluster, but I am having some issues.
The error log is attached below.
(https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xrOBaYqcJ8sKsRZCmTm8dLn8qHzsA4GA/view?usp=sharing)

My Code:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.SharedCacheClientImpl;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.yarn.conf.YarnConfiguration;
import org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.records.ApplicationId;

val scmClient = new SharedCacheClientImpl();
val config = new Configuration();
scmClient.init(config);
scmClient.start();
val cachedPath=scmClient.use(ApplicationId.fromString("application_1689111176927_9999"), "4355a46b19d348dc2f57c046f8ef63d4538ebb936000f3c9ee954a27460dd865");
```

My cluster information is as follows:
* Hadoop: 3.1.0
* Kerberos authentication: Yes

I tried to tarce the log and source code, but I didn't find any clue about Kerberos auth for YARN shared cache.

Can anyone help me to identify the cause of this issue?